# Are there no awaitable ReadAsync/ReceiveAsync options for sockets in .Net Framework?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I know that in .Net Core and Standard we have methods like `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` but this method isn't available in .NetFramework.

Are any of this sort of awaitable method available in .Net Framework, or must such developers stick with Begin/EndXXX or the cumbersome asyncronous methods pre-TPL?

Just want to double-check before writing code on this basis.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 and later supports the [.NET Standard assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), so you should be able to use methods like `ReadAsync`. It requires to install a lot of dependencies and you'll probably face with some issues regarding assemblies versions, but anyway, it's possible

Comment: Actually, [System.Net.Sockets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Sockets/) doesn't have any dependencies for .NET 4.6, but has some for .NET Standard 1.3

Comment: Probably not OK in my case to add all those dependencies but it it might be worth providing an answer as others might be able to use that approach.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Turns out the original answer is wrong as per Stephen Cleary's answer.

There's no `ReadAsync` method ***defined by*** `NetworkStream` as per docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netframework-4.8

**BUT `NetworkStream` inherits it from `Stream`.**

For any begin end method pair which does not have task equivalent, can use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to create one:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I think `FromAsync` might be the answer I'm looking for here. Very interesting, thanks I don't know I would've found that.

Answer (score 3):

`NetworkStream` derives from `Stream`, which [has `ReadAsync` methods on the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?term=Stream.ReadAsync&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I actually found this through Intellisense accidentally. I was sure it was there but couldn't find it in the docs. So... does this definitely mean `NetworkSteam` does have modern async functionality? If so I think you have the preferred answer

Comment: Yes, `NetworkStream` has a TAP async API. I believe the overrides present on newer platforms are just to make it more efficient.

Comment: Looks like MS docs is useless. I will update my incorrect answer.

Comment: @weichch they are confusing in that base methods are often not mentioned. Hard to keep track.